# How to manually toggle a button getting pressed in kivy python?

Tags: python, kivy

I am setting the state of the button to "down" in the py file (and later to "normal" on the event of touch_up), but the on_press in the kv file is not working, nothing happens when I click the button. How could I fix this so that I could make things happen when the button is pressed?

Python:

```py
if touch.y/self.height > 0 and touch.y/self.height < 0.155 and 0.5 < touch.x/self.width < 1:
    self.results.opacity = 0.5
    self.results.state = "down"
    #self.manager.current = "sc2"
    touch.x = 0
    touch.y = 0
```

Kv:

```
Button:
    id: results
    text: "See results"
    on_press:
        print("hey")
```

Comment: Try adding `self.results.dispatch('on_press')` after the line: `self.results.state = "down"`.

Comment: Thank you so much! @JohnAnderson